# WebRTC listen if it requests access to microphone

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc, opentok

I am currently using a service called OpenTok which relies on WebRTC for communicating peer to peer online with video and audio.

In the browser it then asks for permission for using the camera.

I am wondering if it's possible to listen to when this ask for permission is triggered? I essentially want to give users more help that they actually need to give the browser access to the camera, by for instance pointing to the button etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Browser requests would vary a lot across vendors, OS, version, etc.  A typical approach is a text blurb on your site warning users about popups for access. e.g. below that applet : http://www.spiralknights.com/play.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the OpenTok documentation:
https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/Publisher.html

You have some events: accessDialogOpened/accessDialogClosed/accessDenied

Comment: this is exactly what is was looking for! these events will enable me to do build my next features! thank you!